# Connect To FTP(Linux) in C#: 'Operation failed'

Tags: c#, ftp

I want Connect to the Ftp in c#.

```
 public static byte[] DownloadFile(int timeout, string ftpServer, string filePath, string username, string password)
    {
     var client = new FtpClient();
        client.Connect(timeout, ftpServer, 21);
        client.Login(timeout, username, password);

        List<FtpItem> ftpItems = client.GetDirectoryList(timeout, directoryPath).ToList();
        return ftpItems;
    }
```

Sucessfull login but when i want to get file

```
        List<FtpItem> ftpItems = client.GetDirectoryList(timeout, directoryPath).ToList();
```

I get this error:`Operation failed.`

and this response:`425 Failed to establish connection.`

Comment: have you tried connecting the same ftp server using an ftp tool? I guess the problem is related to the server not the c# program.

Comment: If an FTP error 425 occurs, this indicates that the server was unable to open the connection back to the client. The most likely cause for this is an FTP client application that is attempting to re-use a socket that is still in the TCP TIME-WAIT state due to an earlier connection that hasn't been timed out yet

Comment: It might be a problem that the FTP server can't open the backchannel like NetStarter said. Another option why this happens might be a firewall. To solve this, change the FTP mode (there is passive and active). Most likely you should try passive mode.