# How can I use VB.net to access a file saved on a Linux based system

Tags: linux, vb.net, file-io

I have been asked to look into extracting saved data from a Linux based HMI into a windows based PC. I write in VB, but have little to no knowledge of linux. I must admit that I do not even know if I have phrased the question correctly. I do know that the data has been saved to ./PJE/thumbdrive/Rivmon/filename.csv and I need to extract this file to the PC.
Can anyone help, or point me in the right direction for information.

Cheers
Paul

Comment: You can see this way http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15984962/connect-to-ftplinux-in-c-operation-failed

Comment: Thank you Kostas, I have FTP file transfer for VB.net. This is in C, but I understand it enough to give it a try, thanks again